# Sending field input to firebase from state

Tags: react-native

I'm currently working on app that has ability to add new tasks, assign them to others and choose due date.
I'd like to start sending the assignee and due date of the task to my firebase.
This is my dropdowncomponent:

```
class DropdownComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      assignee: '',
    data: [{
      value: 'apple',
    }, {
      value: 'lemon',
    }, {
      value: 'orange',
    }, {
      value: 'banana',
    }, {
      value: 'watermelon',
    }],
    value: ''
    }
  }



  handleAssigneePicked = value => {
    this.setState({ assignee: value })
    console.log("Assignee " + value)
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <Dropdown
        data={this.state.data}
        value={this.state.assignee}
        onChangeText={this.handleAssigneePicked}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

And this is how I render datepicker

```
 <DateTimePicker
          isVisible={this.state.isDateTimePickerVisible}
          onConfirm={this.handleDatePicked}
          onCancel={this.hideDateTimePicker}

        />

  handleDatePicked = date => {
    console.log("A date has been picked: ", date);
    this.hideDateTimePicker();
    this.setState({ selectedDate: moment().format('D MMM DD YYYY HH:MM')})
  };
```

When I choose an item from dropdown, it also console logs the corresponding value, meaning the state changed, no issues there.

However, if i'm trying to send that information to firebase, using code below:

```
const SaveNewTask = (name, body) => {
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-expressions
  !!name && !!body 
    ? 
      firebase
      .database()
      .ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/tasks`)
      .push({
        name, body, assignee, selectedDate, timestamp: Date.now(), completed: false, archived: false
      })
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    : alert('All fields are required.');
};
```

But I'm getting can't find variable: assignee and selectedDate, can I get some help with this? I must be missing something little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to pass these params to action

```
const SaveNewTask = (name, body, assignee, selectedDate) => {
const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();

!_.isEmpty(name) && !_.isEmpty(body) && !_.isEmpty(assignee) && selectedDate != undefined
  ? 
    firebase
    .database()
    .ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/tasks`)
    .push({
      name, body, assignee, selectedDate, timestamp: Date.now(), completed: false, archived: false
    })

  : alert('All fields are required.');
};
```

you can use `_.isEmpty()` by [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEmpty)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that makes my alert modal appear for few milliseconds and then dissappearing, which makes the app unresponsive and i have to restart app to make it work again.